# error when running chat app on simulator xcode iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, xmpp

I am working on xmpp for jabber client on iPhone specifying server name as gmail.com. When I run it on iPhone it works ok giving all the available friends list but when I run it on simulator it gives me an error on console:

```
Error Domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainNetDB Code=8 "nodename nor servname provided, or not known" UserInfo=0x4f7bbb0 {NSLocalizedDescription=nodename nor servname provided, or not known}.
```

Also I can't debug it neither on iPhone nor on simulator.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I too experienced the same. @vikas did you fixed it

Comment: Its worked when I set port to 5222 to xmppStream. They says they will take 5222 as default port don't know why its working after I did it.